# Loading Multiple HTML,CSS and JS Files in a Single HTML File

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 multiple HTML,CSS and JS Files.
I need to load all these Files in a single HTML Page.
I need to display all the content from 4 HTMl Pages in a Single HTML Page without copying the contents.
Can i import 4 HTML Pages in one HTML Page ?
If i am loading 4 different Charts in 4 different HTML Pages,Can i load those 4 Charts in Single HTML Page without Copying the Contents from 4 Different HTML Page.

Comment: As Nike would say... Just Do It.

Comment: Sorry but you're not giving us enough details...can you be more precise?

Comment: *"Can you please help me out in this"* - No one here can help you unless you edit your question and add some more data - What is the project's folder structure? What are the JS files ? What do you mean by "conflicts" ?

Comment: Can you refer any link or tutorial to do this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to put an html file inside another one just copy the content of what's inside the  tag inside the body of another.
Basically have just one main page with the  and  tag and inside that page copy everything inside the  tags.
Now include all your CSS inside the  tag of the page you are left with and include the JS either in the header tag or at the end of the  (recommended).

Comment: I need to import those HTML Content of Multiple pages in a single Html page.

Comment: yes but the HTML content should just be the content of what is inside the <body></body> tags so just take that of 3 of the 4 html pages and paste it inside the body tag of the 4th page

Comment: I don't want to paste the code, I want to externally load the code from the single page. Is there any way ?

Comment: In that cas you will have to use templates like Twig to include part of a file inside another file.
https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/